# How can i pass a document from nodejs to ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs, template-engine

Well i access a file from somewhere and i want to pass it to embedded java script(ejs)template. How do i pass that file from node end point to embedded java script  template.

Comment: By "Passing a file" do you mean you're passing file location or content of a file?

Comment: lets say i access a file or document from input form and when i get that file i want to send it to another ejs file for some processing.

Comment: What kind of file ? You want to display the raw content of file ? What kind of processing do you want to apply ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const path = 'path-of-your-file';
const content = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');

const result = ejs.render(content, {variable: 'value'});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Of course, this only makes sense if the file is a "text" file of some form with `utf-8` or `utf-16` characters.